# Data attribute bound to external variable not reactive to variable changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm beginning to incorporate Vue.js (v2.5.17) for a few small things on an ecommerce website, but I'm new to Vue and having some troubles. Due to some Laravel blade structure that I don't have the option of refactoring at this time, I have to split the various parts of this functionality into distinct components, and I'm having trouble with the data in one Vue instance reacting to events on the other.

Here's a CodePen with a stripped down version of the issue: https://codepen.io/jgabrielsen/pen/bxRroM/

For easy reference, the JS:

```
var cartStore = {
    state: {
        products: [PRODUCT ARRAY],
        active: false
    },
}

var cartHeader = new Vue({
    el: '#cartHeader',
    data: {
        products: cartStore.state.products,
    },
    methods: {
        setActiveTrue: function() {
            cartStore.state.active = true;
            console.log('Show Cart');
        },
        setActiveFalse:function() {
            cartStore.state.active = false;
            console.log('Hide Cart');
        },          
    },
})

var cartPreview = new Vue({
    el: '#cartPreview',
    data: {
        products: cartStore.state.products,
        active: cartStore.state.active,
    },
    methods: {
        total: function() {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
                sum += this.products[i][1]
            }
            return sum
        },
    },
})
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <a id="cartHeader" @mouseover="setActiveTrue" @mouseout="setActiveFalse">CART({{ this.products.length }})</a>
</div>

<div id="cartPreview" v-show="active">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="product in products">
            <div class="col-80">
                {{ product[0] }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-20" style="text-align:right;">
                ${{ product[1] }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-100" style="text-align:right;">
            Total Products: {{ this.products.length }}<br>
            Total: ${{ this.total() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Long story short, I need the `cartPreview` instance to show up when `cartHeader` instance is hovered over (a basic popover effect).

Here's how I'm currently trying to do this:

- I have a `var cartStore` that contains an array of all the cart preview data, as well as an `active` state.
- `cartPreview` has a data attribute `active` bound to `cartStore.state.active` (which is false by default) `and v-show="active"`, so it's hidden until something sets it's data attribute `active` to `true`.
- `cartHeader` has `@mouseover="setActiveTrue"` and `@mouseout="setActiveFalse"`, to toggle `cartPreview`'s `active` attribute by way of the bound state in `cartStore`.

I can tell that the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are firing because `cartStore.state.active` does change to `true` and `false` correctly and the console logs fire, but the corresponding data attribute in the `cartPreview` is not reactive to these changes.

I feel like I must be overlooking something super simple and/or making some major noob mistakes, but after poring over my code dozens of times and searching high and low, I'm stumped as to why it's not reactive.

Comment: `cartStore` doesn't exist anywhere inside of Vue, so any changes made to it will have no effect on your Vue components. You should probably only use `new Vue` once on a parent element, and create `header` and `preview` as components with `Vue.component`. If you have them as separate `new Vue` like you have currently, it won't be easy to communicate between them.

Comment: As I mentioned, using `new Vue` on a parent element isn't an option. It's not ideal, but it's the situation I'm saddled with.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a solution.

`cartStore.state.products` *was* reactive between `cartHeader` and `cartPreview` for adding and removing the products (methods I removed from my example because I didn't think they were relevant), but `cartStore.state.active` wasn't. The only difference I could see was that the cart data in `products` was stored in an array and `active` wasn't, so I made `cartStore.state.active` an array:

```
var cartStore = {
    state: {
        products: [PRODUCT ARRAY],
        active: [ false ]
    },
}
```

...updated it with `splice`:

```
methods: {
    setActiveTrue: function() {
        this.active.splice(0,1,true);
    },
    setActiveFalse:function() {
        this.active.splice(0,1,false);
    },          
},
```

...and added `v-show="active[0]"` to the component, and lo and behold, it works.